# perl object method refer use string

Tags: perl

perl object "**plan**" has subroutine "**plan_exec_time**";

```
my $p = Plan->new;
```

i can call it by this way : `$p->plan_exec_time`

but `$p->"plan_exec_time"` dos not works.

now i want access the subroutine by variable refer:

```
my $t = "plan_exec_";

$p->"${t}time"
```

this is also not works

how to access the object's subroutine but donot through create an temp variable ?

because this works :

```
my $x = "${t}time";
$p->$x;
```

Comment: Can you show what error message you are getting when calling this function?

Comment: Check the path of the `Plan` module.
Like this: `perl -e Plan.pm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $t = "plan_exec";
$p->can($t."_time")->($p)
```

The `can` method returns ref to the method.

Comment: some explanation would help the OP

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to avoid using a temporary variable - any other solution will be ugly and hacky. But you can reference and dereference a string in one go, like this

```
my $p = Plan->new;
my $t = "plan_exec_";
$p->${\"${t}time"};
```